# How to set a button visible only when a panel is collapsed

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

there is a way to set a button visible only when a panel is collapsed? I tried the bellow code but without success. I also tried to use getElementById("#closeButton").style.visibility but it still not working.

```js
function checkCollapsed(){
  
 if($("#panel").hasClass('ui-collapsible-collapsed')){
     $("#closeButton").hide();
 }else{
   $("#closeButton").show();
 }
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="panel-group col-lg-1">
   <div class="panel panel-default">
     <div class="panel-heading">
       <h4 class="panel-title">
         <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#panel" onclick="checkCollapsed()">test</a>
         <button id="closeButton" type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" >
           <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
         </button>
       </h4>
     </div>
     <div id="panel" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        blablabla
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `if($("#panel").hasClass('ui-collapsible-collapsed'))` does not seem valid to me..There is no class added for `#panel`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.in` class is being added to `#panel` element. `ui-collapsible-collapsed` remain there all the time.

```js
function checkCollapsed() {
  if ($("#panel").hasClass('in')) {
    $("#closeButton").hide();
  } else {
    $("#closeButton").show();
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="panel-group col-lg-1">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
         <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#panel" onclick="checkCollapsed()">test</a>
         <button id="closeButton" type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" >
           <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
         </button>
       </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="panel" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      blablabla
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I supose that the problem is when your click, is before change the class.
One idea is to make a little timeout:

```
function checkCollapsed(){
  setTimeout(function(){
if($("#panel").hasClass('ui-collapsible-collapsed')){
     $("#closeButton").hide();
 }else{
   $("#closeButton").show();
 }
}, 110);

}
```

The idea is take a time to collapside panel to change status, and class.
Expect it help